# Create dropdown category filter

Tags: php, arrays, filter

There is a .txt file that saves every record from the input.
I read the file and explode it by specific char. There is sum of all the values in the 3-th column. I want to implement a category filter option.

My code so far :

```
<?php
                if(file_exists('store.txt')){ 
                    $result=file('store.txt');
                    foreach($result as $value){ 
                         $columns =  explode('!', $value);  
                         $price = array($columns[2]); 
                         $sum += $price[0]; 

                         if(isset($_POST['filter'])){ //There's the part with the filter
                             $filter = $_POST['category'];



                         }

                         echo 
                              '<tr><td>'.$columns[0].'</td>
                              <td>'.$columns[1].'</td>
                              <td>'.$columns[2].'</td>
                              <td>'.$columns[3].'</td></tr>';
                        }
                }
                             ?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing values from text file on server into HTML table with the option to limit results, sum'img price, using PHP.

getstore.php:

```
if(file_exists('store.txt')) {
    $result=file('store.txt');

    $filter = 'no';
    if ( isset($_POST['filter']) ) {
        $filter = $_POST['filter'];
        echo 'Filter = "' . $filter . '"';
    }
    else { echo 'No filter selected.'; }

    if ( 0 < count($result) ) {
        echo '<table border="1"><tr><th>column 1</th><th>column 2</th><th>price</th><th>filter</th></tr>';

        $sum = 0;
        foreach($result as $value) {

            $columns =  explode('!', $value);

            if ( 'no' == $filter || trim($columns[3]) == $filter ) {
                $sum += $columns[2]; // add price to total
                echo '<tr><td>'.$columns[0].'</td><td>'.$columns[1].'</td><td>'.$columns[2].'</td><td>'.$columns[3].'</td></tr>';
            }
        }
        echo "<tr><td></td><td align=\"right\"><strong>SUM:</strong></td><td>$sum</td><td></td></tr></table>";
    }
    else { 'Empty file.'; }
}
else { echo 'File not found.'; }

?>

<form action="getstore.php" method="post">
    <select name="filter">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I select filter 2, gives me:

```
Filter = "2"
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>column 1</th>
        <th>column 2</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>filter</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 4, column 1, index 0</td>
        <td>column 2, index 1</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 5, column 1, index 0</td>
        <td>column 2, index 1</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 6, column 1, index 0</td>
        <td>column 2, index 1</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><strong>SUM:</strong></td>
        <td>90</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I did it but it's on the other file with the input form.

Comment: So columns is an array and columns[2] is a value from the whole array, if you foreach it You will get simply a string.So I made a new array of this value of the existing array to facilitate my sum procedure.That is my logic.Please correct me if It is impressingly wrong.

Comment: Oookay.This doesn't work on my own. Please if you have some suggestions on how to build it.Contact me and in this time I'll think about it and will share a result if a get something.So to let the begginers like know how to do that.

Comment: No. Just getting nothing. Nothing happend.

Comment: Alrighty then.So I get the Result which is a huge array of every inputed record in the table.So every record with some data that is made from the other form file is displaying on this table.
So I guess i have to say "When I click category == 2 show me the arrays with 3th key == 2 when i make a POST query by clicking this button and so on.. But I don't really see any ways to do that."

Comment: This line `if ( 'no' == $filter || $columns[3] == $filter ) {` is limiting what gets printed to the screen if the filter has been submitted.

Comment: Does't really make anything.I know how to choose a certain key of the array which is the selected TYPE menu, but don't know how to tell it to display only certain elements of the whole array.I'm really a beginner, just started learning how to code and don't have any previous expierence.So please help me.

Comment: It says 'No filter selected' and it stays on the screen.When you choose a filter the table disappears and it keep saying the same.

Comment: OBJECT NOT FOUND!
So I think I need something like this

Comment: if($_POST['filter]'){
If($_POST['category']){
if(key($category) == $columns[3]) {
DISPLAY THE RECORDS WITH COLUMNS3 = the values that is selected
}
}
}

Comment: Ah, my fault, PHP `explode` doesn't trim the line return from the last column in the "store.txt" file, which happens to be the filter field comparison. So, added PHP `trim()` to filter field. See updated response.